# Directorio raiz Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

que tal? Tengo el siguiente problema:

En mi pc, en el wamp, tengo cargado una pagina hecha en wordpress. Por defecto los links empiezan con http://localhost/final/. El tema es que cuando subo la pagina a internet siguen con esa direccion y para arreglarlo tengo que ir a la base de datos y cambiar todos los http://localhost/final/ por la direccion del sitio web. Lo que quiero es alguna manera de cambiar desde wordpress o desde el servidor para que los links se guarden en el root "/" asi no importa donde suba los archivos, el directorio sea siempre la raiz de donde lo cargue.

Espero puedan ayudarme, un saludo!

Comment: Qué tal si usas unplugin para migrarlo como All-In-One WP Migration plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

entiendo un poco este pequeño inconveniente, pero te voy a dar este código para que en una consulta SQL puedas cambiar rápidamente la url en la base de datos.

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE ( option_value, 'http://vieja.url', 'http://nueva.url' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE ( guid, 'http://vieja.url', 'http://nueva.url' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'http://vieja.url', 'http://nueva.url' );

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE ( meta_value, 'http://vieja.url', 'http://nueva.url' );